# Query works in microsoft query in Excel but not in Visual Studio asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Hello I have a query that combines two tables. It runs fine in excel however it times out in VS10 when trying to add it to a gridview. ODBC is ProvideX , it isn't very flexible... it won't even let me use a join but my code and query is below. Any questions let me know, Thank you!

```
SELECT CWIPH.CUST_NO, CWIPH.JOB_NAME, CJCMS.JOB_DESC
FROM CJCMS CJCMS, CWIPH CWIPH
WHERE CWIPH.JOB_NO = CJCMS.JOB_NO
```

asp

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Dsn=Jake" ProviderName="System.Data.Odbc" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT CWIPH.CUST_NO, CWIPH.JOB_NAME, CJCMS.JOB_DESC
    FROM CJCMS CJCMS, CWIPH CWIPH
    WHERE CWIPH.JOB_NO = CJCMS.JOB_NO">
```

Comment: What part is timing out?  Is it the connection to your DSN or the query execution itself?  How long does excel take to run the query is it longer than say 30 seconds?

Comment: I created a test page just to time the query in vs and it never loads. Excel is almost instant. Ive tired on localhost and also vs debug